# visual studio 2010 debugger find goto current line stopped at shortcut key

Tags: debugging, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper, shortcut

1) I put a breakpoint, VS breaks where I put the breakpoint.

2) I then start browsing around the code normally to put another breakpoint 
somewhere down the execution path. (maybe in another class in some other cs file)

3) I would now like to return to where I first stopped  (just navigation in the code. Do not confuse with the go back in debugger feature used in VS's intellitrace debugging tool)

Right now I place a bookmark and return to my bookmark. But I forget most of times to place a bookmark. Hence this question. There's got to be a shortcut to get back to current line of execution or stopped at or whatever phrase is used to describe this. I also have Resharper if I can craft up some hotkey or shortcut. Anyway I can get back to where the debugger has "broken". I sometimes also use Ctrl - multiple times to navigate backwards.
thank you

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That would be the Visual Studio command "Debug.ShowNextStatement" (usually assigned to Alt+Num*). You can also use the Breakpoints Window (Alt+Ctrl+B) to navigate between your breakpoints.

**UPDATE:** I implemented @Alex 's request for a more discoverable and accessible MenuItem for this functionality, as part of a commercial Visual Studio extension I created called [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com). It works similarly to Resharper's Context Actions: when you are in break mode but have navigated far away from the 'current statement', this [QuickAction](http://o.oz-code.com/features#quickAction) will appear:

[image: ShowNextStatement]

Comment: Been looking for this for a while, thanks! Why oh why did they not put this not in the main Debug menu?

Answer (score 16):

I tend to use the call stack window, double click the top line in the stack trace causes the editor window to display the code line where execution halted